# Cannot go to other pages after open ForgotPassword link

Tags: community, forgot-your-password, change-password

In our community we have "Reset your password" page which simply run the following code: `Site.forgotPassword(username);`

Then user receives an email with a link: https://XXX.XXX.force.com/XXX/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?r=XXX&display=page&fpot=XXX

It leads a user to a page where he can change his password. Changing password works as expected. But, if he opens that link and doesn't change a password, then he can't go to any other page (Login, Register, etc.).

User clicks links, browser changes url, but the page remains the same, asking user to enter new password. Open other pages in different tabs doesn't help. Only closing the browser, or deleting cookies helps.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that's an intentional feature. You're not going to be able to change that.